# Git alias for clearing old branches is failing.. why?

Tags: git, alias, git-config

Ive made a new git alias to clear out all my old unused git branches but its crashing my git config when i add it? I don't see why since it worked in my bash when i put it in earlier. Or I thought it did anyway!

`clean-unused = "!git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|develop)" | xargs git branch -d"`

Ive added the ! before the first git command as I understand this will open a new shell to run the command in.

What seems to be the problem here?

The crashing message from git:
`fatal: bad config line 11 in file /Users/<userName>/.gitconfig`

Comment: Try to escape internal dquotes: `clean-unused = "!git branch --merged | egrep -v \"(^\*|develop)\" | xargs git branch -d"`

Comment: didnt seem to work for me still after trying this.

Comment: Also escape backslashes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape inner double quotes and backslashes:

```
clean-unused = "!git branch --merged | egrep -v \"(^\\*|develop)\" | xargs git branch -d"
```

Just tested, works for me.